# Capture the traffic generated by a browser using wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

How can I capture only the traffic generated by a web browser using Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Network Monitor, there you can just get the traffic from a browser or a program.

Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865

Comment: Is the there any alternative for linux?

Comment: Could you please give what filter to use to capture only the traffic generated by chrome

Comment: Wireshark can't filter using process as far as I know